# Can't properly evaluate a limit algebraically.

Tags: limits

I tried my best to evaluate this as the  limit approaches zero. The textbook says it should approach two but I get zero.  $$\frac{2(x+\Delta x)-2x}{\Delta x} =\frac{2x+2\Delta x-2x}{\Delta x}=\frac{ 2\Delta x}{\Delta x}=\Delta x $$

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Your computations are difficult to read. Is it suppose to be a ratio?

Comment: What is the limit? $x \to 0$? Or is this a ratio and you omitted the bars, meaning we get everything in terms of infinitesimals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start with the expression 
$$\frac{2(x+\Delta x)-2x}{\Delta x}$$
$$=\frac{2x+2\Delta x-2x}{\Delta x}$$
$$=\frac{2\Delta x}{\Delta x}$$
$$=2\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta x}$$
At this point we have an infinitesimal over itself, and we know have the definition that $\frac{a}{a} = 1$
$$=2(1)$$
$$=2$$

Answer (score 0):

You canceled the wrong thing out in the last step. You wrote $\frac{2 \Delta x}{\Delta x} = \Delta x$. Instead, the $\Delta x$'s cancel and you get 2.

Answer (score 0):

@JoshuaMorris, you have it correct EXCEPT for the last step where you subtract the denominator from the numerator. You just need to divide both by the common factor i.e. DELTA x and you will get 2.